# JAVA EE web application and big traffic

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I choose `java` to make my web application with `maven` + `hibernate` + `spring MVC` + `apache tomcat server` (`Java EE`).
My web application will have many users and many visitors every day.

But my friend told me that web application with java don't support a lot of connections and it's made just for Intranet and business application with network within an organization.

So is it true `apache tomcat` can't handle all that traffic ?

i'm not looking for who is the best between `java`, `php` and `.NET` i want just know if web application with java can handle a big traffic ?

also explain me if there is some other negative points of using `java` and `apache tomcat` server.

Comment: Your friend doesn't know what he is talking about / hates Java and thus says negative things about it. No verifiable source = not true.

Comment: make sure you do connection pooling and close all connections as here - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java)

Comment: Their is no such comparison between technology. Lots of web sites working on java and tomcat. you have develop web site with proper optimized code with some good application and database server configuration and settings.

Comment: It is tremendously easy to write bad software in any platform! Whether it's .NET, php, or Java you can easily create a site that would not scale at all

Comment: Not true, I would even say java js better. Hibernate can slow down, JSF needs some care. Positive is the type-safe rock-solid programming you can do. Negative is the frameworks garbage one has to learn.

Comment: If you get to the point that a single tomcat instance cannot handle the traffic that your application is receiving, you should be using other methods of mitigating that load, whether it be through local caching, load balancing among multiple nodes, or perhaps utilizing a CDN to cache content globally.

Answer (score 2):

The Java based technology stack you describe is extremely scalable, if you want it to be, and I would have no worries about using it for high traffic applications.

You may want to look at distributed hosting and load balancing, to make things more reliable. Lots of high traffic applications use Java and Spring stacks.

Answer (score -4):

using plain old jsp/servlets are faster than spring and hibernate because spring or hibernate have a middle tier with classes which renders the page slowly and takes more memory at the server.

For production environs with huge scale applications you will end up writing plain jsp/servlets as they are a breeze to write and maintain.

Also i would like to add that struts library(jar file) had some security vulnerabilities in late 2013 only. Stay away from Struts and Spring.

People may be down voting but there is truth behind what i have actually experienced.

Comment: Servlets and JSPs are a breeze to maintain? I would have to disagree :)

Comment: Actually no. The big popular frameworks(like SpringMvc, Struts2 etc..) are not slower than plain jsp/servlets. They provide the programmer with the best coding practices(which makes the app really faster), they solve many of his structural problems, and they are SO much easier to maintain than plain JSP/Servlets. Jsp and Servlets today are good for educational purposes and not for production environments.