# How to solve ORA-12516 error?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, error-handling

I am using oracle database 10g express edition. Recently I am facing ORA-12516 error frequently. It says -- 
"java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
//127.0.0.1:1521/XE"

As far as I am concerned this error is shown when user doesn't close variables like "Statement" "Resultset" and opens a lot of them.
Every time I created any "Statement" or "ResultSet" type variables in a function I used this function -- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7902053/    to close those variables. I didn't close those variables in a final block of the function inside which those were declared. Instead I called this function (close_calls(..)) to close those variables and sent them as parameters inside the function close_calls(..). For example I called the function given above in no 17 and 23 line here -- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7902114/

But this error is still shown in the console. Is close_call(...) not working ? How can I get rid of this error ? I got the idea of closing those variables from here --- [Closing Database Connections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java)

Comment: There seems to be many open connections,so your DB is refusing additional connections. 
Quickest answer is to restart your DB ( If you have made proper closure of SQL Objects in your Java)

Comment: Please see my comment to HAL 9000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is leaking **connections** (not cursors or statements).

You've got to close the connections too, not only the statements and result sets  - just as suggested by answer of that question you linked to.

Comment: For the last code I was getting 4 ora-12516 errors.After changing I am still getting one ora-12516 error. Here I have shown a sample of many functions that use the database --- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7903343/
get_course_id_list() is the sample function. This is how I tried to close connections after working with each function -- http://paste.ubuntu.com/7903351/
close_call(..) is called from every function that has called establishConnection(..).Difference is in the previous code "Connection conn" was static and was not sent as parameter.Why 1 ora-12516 is still shown ? is my close_call() ok ?

Comment: rethink your usage of try catch

Comment: I disagree. You can be in a situation where you need more connections.