# Why "SQL> show parameter processes" command is not working?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle 10g express edition. I ran the command in sql command line and it says -- "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

PS: Trying to access and increase the number of processes. Cause I am facing this problem -- [How to solve ORA-12516 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030413/how-to-solve-ora-12516-error/25030515?noredirect=1#comment38934689_25030515)

Comment: what user/schema do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by "user/schema" ? I have connected sqlcommand line to oracle using "connect username/password"

Comment: to perform DML/DDL/DCL statements you have to be connected to oracle as some user, for oracle user == schema, what user/schema did you use to connect to the DB?

Comment: I connected to oracle as a user.

Comment: Read This Fine Manual. You can't work with oracle only by taking advices from StackOverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running this command as a non-privileged user. `show parameter` is just a fancy wrapper for `select ... from v$parameter`. You need `SELECT` privileges on this view:

```
grant select on v_$parameter to <username>;
```

(please note the `_` in the view name - you cannot directly grant privileges on `v$` views, you have to grant privileges on the underlying objects instead).

Of course, the simplest approach is to run `show parameter` as a DBA user.

Comment: Thanks, man. I didn't know about the v_$parameter view. I tried to grant select on the v$parameter view but this view is a dynamic view.