# using DBUtils with mysql and tomcat 7, getting 'Too many connections' from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

it happens almost once a day when mysql says 'Too many connections'. I've been searching for the solution on google for a while, but no help.
I'd appreciate it if you would help me! Thanks!

I'm using DBUtils in my program with a database connection pool configured in server.xml of a Tomcat 7. (I have two instances of tomcat 7 with the same configuration, but I keep only one of them running, I'll shut down the current one before I start the other one.)

Here is How I get the connection, from the DB class:

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName());
private static DataSource ds = null;
private static Context initCtx = null; 

static {
    try {
        initCtx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ens");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e);
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();
    return con;
}

public static QueryRunner getRunner() {
    return new QueryRunner();
}
```

Here is how I do queries with the method selectList:

```
protected Connection conn;
protected void getConnection() throws SQLException {
    this.conn = DB.getConnection();
}

protected void close() {
    DbUtils.closeQuietly(this.conn);
}

protected <T> List<T> selectList(String sql, Class<T> c, Page p,
        Object... params) throws SQLException {
    try {
        this.getConnection();
        QueryRunner runner = DB.getRunner();
        sql = sql  + this.getLimitClause(p);
        log.debug("selectList - " +sql);
        return runner.query(this.conn, sql,
                new BeanListHandler<T>(c), params);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        throw e;
    } finally {
        this.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration in server.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ens"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
  testWhileIdle="true"
  testOnBorrow="true"
  testOnReturn="false"
  validationQuery="SELECT 1"
  validationInterval="30000"
  timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
  maxActive="270"
  minIdle="10"
  maxWait="10000"
  initialSize="20"
  removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
  removeAbandoned="true"
  logAbandoned="true"
  minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
  jmxEnabled="true"
  jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
  username="root"
  password="root"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/chineselearning?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8"/>
```

the max connections of mysql is set to 300 in my.ini

> max_connections=300

here is the result of 'show processlist' from mysql when it says 'too many connections'

> 1 govoluble   localhost:1033  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   2   govoluble   localhost:1035  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   3   govoluble   localhost:1036  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   4   govoluble   localhost:1037  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   5   govoluble   localhost:1038  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   6   govoluble   localhost:1039  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   7   govoluble   localhost:1040  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   8   govoluble   localhost:1041  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   9   govoluble   localhost:1042  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   10  govoluble   localhost:1043  chineselearning Sleep   56
>   946 govoluble   localhost:3146  chineselearning Sleep   3569
>   947 govoluble   localhost:3147  chineselearning Sleep   3569
>   948 govoluble   localhost:3163  chineselearning Sleep   2694
>   1186    govoluble   localhost:1869  chineselearning Query   94  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1217    govoluble   localhost:1930  chineselearning Sleep   5
>   1218    govoluble   localhost:1931  chineselearning Query   121 Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1219    govoluble   localhost:1932  chineselearning Sleep   5
>   1220    govoluble   localhost:1933  chineselearning Query   121 Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1221    govoluble   localhost:1934  chineselearning Query   121 Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1222    govoluble   localhost:1935  chineselearning Query   121 Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1224    govoluble   localhost:1937  chineselearning Query   121 Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1225    govoluble   localhost:1938  chineselearning Sleep   21
>   1840    govoluble   localhost:2768  chineselearning Sleep   23
>   1841    govoluble   localhost:2770  chineselearning Sleep   23
>   1842    govoluble   localhost:2772  chineselearning Sleep   23
>   1843    govoluble   localhost:2773  chineselearning Query   32  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1844    govoluble   localhost:2774  chineselearning Query   32  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1845    govoluble   localhost:2775  chineselearning Query   14  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1846    govoluble   localhost:2776  chineselearning Query   32  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1847    govoluble   localhost:2777  chineselearning Query   0   Sending data    select count(1) from message where recipient=348 and hasRead=0 and recipientdeleted = 0 and system=0
>   1848    govoluble   localhost:2778  chineselearning Query   32  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1849    govoluble   localhost:2779  chineselearning Query   32  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1850    govoluble   localhost:2780  chineselearning Query   12  Locked  update entry set watch=watch+1 where id=563
>   1851    govoluble   localhost:2782  chineselearning Sleep   23
>   1852    govoluble   localhost:2784  chineselearning Sleep   23
>   1853    govoluble   localhost:2786  chineselearning Sleep   0
>   1854    govoluble   localhost:2788  chineselearning Sleep   23
>   1855    govoluble   localhost:2790  chineselearning Query   23  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1856    govoluble   localhost:2792  chineselearning Query   15  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1857    govoluble   localhost:2794  chineselearning Sleep   23
>   1858    govoluble   localhost:2796  chineselearning Query   23  Copying to tmp table    select e.* from entry as e left join correction as c on e.id = c.entry where e.type=1 group by e.id 
>   1859    govoluble   localhost:2809  chineselearning Query   0       show processlist

Comment: I think part of your problem is that you aren't closing everything opened.  You may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2225275/67566

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the reply, but the close method is explicitly called in the finally block?

Comment: If you look at the link I gave, close is called three times.