# Java/SQL: Is it mandatory to close() a ResultSet / Statement / Connection?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I have to program a Web Crawler (uni assignment), thus I have to store/read/update lots of data to/from a MySQL Database.

I'm using JDBC connector and on **every-time I call a method** to contact the database 
**I'm defining a PreparedStatement & ResultSet and finally i close the RS and finally the PS.**

However I use the same methods so many times that instead of making the program more Time/Resource Efficient I'm making it slower/heavier (that's why I don't close the connection too). So the question is there any other reason to close those or should I let them open?

If I don't close them the program seems not to have any issue but I don't want it to seem correct but truly be.

Edit: Thanks for the ideas on how to close but the question is not How to but "Is it mandatory". Closing makes the program slow so I need to know if I cannot close (seems that it's bad practise) or at least **find a better alternative**.

Comment: please reaad this.. it will answer you questions.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java

Answer (score 3):

- It's always best practice to define `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` locally (i.e. in a method) and `close` them once the execution is done.
- `PreparedStatement` acts as a cursor between your program and database, and if not closed, might result in `maximum open cursors exceeded` error (in case of `Oracle`) as number of cursors/descriptors that can be open are limited per connection.
- As far as closing `ResultSet` is concerned, closing `PreparedStatement` automatically closes `ResultSet` ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) is the javadoc). Ideally, you should be using [try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block for implementation.

Comment: I will test try-with-sources instead of finally-try-finally-try. Connection should close too or not? Maybe if that's needed I can restart the connection once in a while