# JDBC not releasing Oracle database cursors

Tags: java, database, jdbc, cursor

I am hitting select queries on 16 tables in the database, for huge data and getting cursor limit exceeds exception.

I have already closed the connection, prepared statement, and resultset but still getting cursor limit exceeds exception.

I closed the connection but still not releasing database cursors

I have closed the connection in the init block as shown in the code snippet below, and already closed the `resultSet` and `preparedStatement` in finally block

Please suggest me how to release cursor to avoid this exception.

Attaching code for reference.

```
public class DataReader {

PDFProperty properties = new PDFProperty();
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
XSSFSheet sheet = null;

private Connection connection;
private PreparedStatement ps;
private ResultSet rs;
private ArrayDeque<String> OHR = new ArrayDeque<String>(18502);
private DataReader reader = null;
private PDFCollection collect;
ArrayDeque<String> OHRArrayList = new ArrayDeque<>();
private String dbArray[] = null;
private PDFProperty prop = null;

Iterator<String> headerIterator = null;
Iterator<List<String>> dataIterator = null;
Iterator<String> nestedIterator = null;
List<String> nestedList = new ArrayList<String>();

private List<List<String>> totalData = new ArrayList<List<String>>(100000);

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
{
    System.out.println("called before constructor......");
    try {
        if(connection!=null)
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public DataReader() {

/*  Connect connect = Connect.getInstance(); 
    connection = connect.getConnection();*/

    Connect connect = new Connect();

      connection = connect.setConnection();


    System.err.println("******************************************************************");

    System.err.println("connection is:"+connection);
    System.err.println("******************************************************************");
}

public ArrayDeque<String> getOHRList() {

    /*
     * Connect connect = Connect.getInstance();
     * 
     * connection = connect.getConnection();
     * 
     * String sql = "select employee_ohr_id from OVERALL_RATING";
     * 
     * try { ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql); rs = ps.executeQuery();
     * 
     * while (rs.next()) { System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
     * 
     * OHR.add(rs.getString(1));
     * 
     * } System.out.println(OHR);
     * 
     * } catch (SQLException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     * e.printStackTrace(); }
     */

    OHR.add("703045278");/*
                             * OHR.add("601002590");
                             * 
                             * OHR.add("601002424");
                             */

    return OHR;

}

public List<String> getTableHeader(String name) {

    List<String> header = new ArrayList<String>();
    String sql = "SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '" + name + "'ORDER BY COLUMN_ID ";
    System.out.println("Header sql :" + sql);

      /*Connect connect = new Connect();

      connection = connect.setConnection();*/

    /*
      Connect connect = Connect.getInstance(); connection =
      connect.getConnection();*/


    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

            header.add(rs.getString(1));

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.commit();
            ps.close();
            rs.close();
            ps=null;
            rs=null;

            System.err.println("result set :"+rs);
            System.err.println("prepared statement :"+ps);


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
    System.out.println("Table Name :" + name);
    System.out.println("Header :" + header);
    return header;

}

/*
 * public static void main(String[] args) { DataReader dr = new
 * DataReader(); System.out.println(dr.getTableHeader("REVIEW_PERIOD")); }
 */

public void getData(String list, PDFCollection col) {

    /*Connect connect = new Connect();

    connection = connect.setConnection();*/

      /*Connect connect = Connect.getInstance(); connection =
              connect.getConnection();*/
    System.out.println("lis is " + list);

    System.out.println("data reader :" + col);
    List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();

    reader = new DataReader();

    /*
     * Connect connect = Connect.getInstance();
     * 
     * connection = connect.getConnection();
     */

    prop = new PDFProperty();

    dbArray = prop.getProperty("TABLE_NAMES").split("~");

    /* for (String list : OHRArrayList) { */
    for (String table : dbArray) {

        List<String> allData = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
        String sql = "";

        /*
         * String sql =
         * "select * from CAREER_PLAN where EMPLOYEE_OHR_ID = '703045278'" ;
         */

        String columnCount = "SELECT count(column_name) FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '" + table + "'";
        int count = 0;
        try {
            //connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(columnCount);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                count = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));

            }

            headers = reader.getTableHeader(table);

            System.out.println("headers :" + headers);

            for (String head : headers) {

                if (head.equals("OHR_ID") || head.equals("EMPLOYEE_OHR_ID")) {

                    sql = "select * from " + table + " where " + head + "= '" + list + "'";
                }
            }

            System.out.println("sql is :" + sql);
            System.out.println(table);

            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql, ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            String res = "";

            while (rs.next()) {

                for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

                    res = rs.getString(i);
                    if (res == null) {
                        res = "";
                    }

                    allData.add(res);
                }

            }

            System.out.println("all data is :" + allData);

            totalData = Lists.partition(allData, count);

            System.out.println(table);
            // System.out.println("total data :" + totalData);

            /*
             * Iterator it = totalData.iterator();
             * 
             * while (it.hasNext()) { System.out.println(it.next());
             * 
             * }
             */

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                System.err.println("inside finally");
                //connection.commit();
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                //System.out.println(rs.);







                // connection.close();
                // connection.close();
                /// System.out.println("connection after ");

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        System.out.println("======================================================================");
        System.out.println(table);
        System.out.println("======================================================================");

        if (table.equals("EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION")) {

            headerIterator = headers.iterator();
            dataIterator = totalData.iterator();

            while (dataIterator.hasNext()) {
                nestedList = dataIterator.next();
                nestedIterator = nestedList.iterator();

            }

            System.out.println("nested List :" + nestedList);
            System.out.println("Employee Headers" + headers);

            if (!(nestedList.isEmpty())) {
                while (headerIterator.hasNext() && nestedIterator.hasNext()) {

                    map.put(headerIterator.next(), nestedIterator.next());
                }

                System.out.println("=============================================================================");
                System.out.println("employee map :" + map);
                System.out.println("=============================================================================");

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> ee : map.entrySet()) {

                    if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("OHR_ID")) {
                        col.setOHR_ID(ee.getValue().trim());
                    }
                    if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME")) {
                        col.setFirst_Name(ee.getValue().trim());
                    }

                    if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("EMPLOYEE_MIDDLE_NAME")) {

                        if (ee.getValue() != null)
                            col.setMiddle_Name(ee.getValue().trim());

                        else
                            col.setMiddle_Name("");
                    }
                    if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME")) {
                        col.setLast_Name(ee.getValue().trim());
                    }
                    if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("FORM_TEMPLATE_NAME")) {
                        col.setTemplate(ee.getValue().trim() + " for");
                    }
                    if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("FORM_COMPLETED_ON_DATE")) {
                        System.out.println(ee.getValue());
                        if (ee.getValue().trim().contains(":")) {
                            String compDate[] = ee.getValue().trim().split("\\s+");
                            col.setFormCompeletionDate(compDate[0]);
                        } else {
                            col.setFormCompeletionDate(ee.getValue().trim());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            col.setOriginator(col.getFirst_Name() + " " + col.getLast_Name() + " (" + col.getOHR_ID() + ")");

        }

        if (table.equals("CAREER_PLAN")) {

            if (totalData.size() == 0) {
                List<List<String>> tempList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                List<String> nullList = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                    nullList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    nullList.add("NO DATA");
                }
                tempList.add(nullList);

                col.setCareerPlanHeader(headers);
                col.setCareerPlanTotalFilteredRows(totalData);
            } else {
                col.setCareerPlanHeader(headers);
                col.setCareerPlanTotalFilteredRows(totalData);

            }

        }
        if (table.equals("COMPETENCIES")) {
            System.out.println("competencies " + totalData);

            if (totalData.size() > 1) {
                List<List<String>> sortedList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                Map keyValueofSortedValue = new HashMap();
                int index = headers.indexOf("COMPETENCY_NAME");

                for (List list1 : totalData) {
                    String value = (String) list1.get(index);
                    String num[] = value.split("\\.");
                    System.out.println(num[0]);
                    keyValueofSortedValue.put(Integer.parseInt(num[0]), list1);
                }
                for (int i = 1; i <= keyValueofSortedValue.size(); i++) {
                    List finalList = (List) keyValueofSortedValue.get(i);
                    sortedList.add(finalList);
                }
                System.out.println("sett head " + headers);
                col.setCompetenciesExcelHeader(headers);
                col.setCompetenciesTotalFilteredRows(sortedList);
            } else {
                col.setCompetenciesExcelHeader(headers);
                col.setCompetenciesTotalFilteredRows(totalData);
            }

        }
        if (table.equals("FEEDBACK_APPRAISAL_PROCESS")) {
            System.out.println("FEEDBACK_ON_APPRAISAL_PROCESS :" + totalData);

            col.setFeedbackHeader(headers);
            col.setFeedbackTotalFilteredRows(totalData);

        }
        if (table.equals("OVERALL_RATING")) {

            System.out.println("inside overall rating" + totalData);

            headerIterator = headers.iterator();
            dataIterator = totalData.iterator();

            while (dataIterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("inside while");
                List nestedList = dataIterator.next();
                nestedIterator = nestedList.listIterator();
            }
            if (!(nestedList.isEmpty())) {

                while (headerIterator.hasNext() && nestedIterator.hasNext()) {

                    map1.put(headerIterator.next(), nestedIterator.next());
                }

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> ee : map1.entrySet()) {
                    if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("OVERALL_PERFORMANCE_RATING")) {
                        if (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            col.setPerformance("1.0 - T20");
                        } else if (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                            col.setPerformance("2.0 - HV70");
                        } else if (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                            col.setPerformance("3.0 - LE10");
                        } else {
                            col.setPerformance("Unrated");
                        }
                    }
                    if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("OVERALL_POTENTIAL_RATING_DESCRIPTION")) {
                        if (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("High")) {
                            col.setPotential("1.0 - High");
                        } else if (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Specialist")) {
                            col.setPotential("2.0 - Specialist");
                        } else if (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Medium")) {
                            col.setPotential("3.0 - Medium");
                        } else if (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Low")) {
                            col.setPotential("4.0 - Low");
                        } else {
                            col.setPotential(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        if (table.equals("REVIEW_PERIOD")) {

            System.out.println("Review headers :" + headers);

            headerIterator = headers.iterator();
            dataIterator = totalData.listIterator();

            while (dataIterator.hasNext()) {
                List nestedList = dataIterator.next();
                nestedIterator = nestedList.listIterator();
            }

            HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while (headerIterator.hasNext() && nestedIterator.hasNext()) {
                map1.put(headerIterator.next(), nestedIterator.next().toString());
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> ee : map1.entrySet()) {
                if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("FORM_START_DATE")) {
                    col.setFormStartDate(ee.getValue().trim());
                }
                if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("FORM_END_DATE")) {
                    col.setFormEndDate(ee.getValue().trim());
                }
                if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("FORM_DUE_DATE")) {
                    col.setDue_Date(ee.getValue().trim());
                }
                if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("ORIGINATOR_FIRST_NAME")) {
                    col.setOrgFirstName(ee.getValue().trim());
                }
                if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("ORIGINATOR_LAST_NAME")) {
                    col.setOrgLastName(ee.getValue().trim());
                }
                if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("ORIGINATOR_OHR_ID")) {
                    col.setOrgOHRId(ee.getValue().trim());
                }
            }
            col.setReview_Period(col.getFormStartDate() + " - " + col.getFormEndDate());

            /*
             * col.setFormStartDate("16-feb-2015");
             * col.setFormEndDate("28-feb-2015"); col.setDue_Date("");
             * col.setOrgFirstName(""); col.setOrgLastName("");
             * col.setOrgOHRId(""); col.setReview_Period(
             * "16-feb-2015 - 28-feb-2015");
             */

        }
        if (table.equals("PROJECT_GOALS")) {

            System.out.println("project goals :" + totalData);
            if (totalData.size() == 0) {
                List<List<String>> tempList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                List<String> nullList = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                    nullList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    nullList.add("NO DATA");
                }
                tempList.add(nullList);

                col.setTotalFilteredRows(tempList);
                col.setExcelHeader(headers);
            } else {
                col.setTotalFilteredRows(totalData);
                col.setExcelHeader(headers);

            }

        }
        if (table.equals("GOALS")) {

            if (totalData.size() == 0) {
                List<List<String>> tempList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                List<String> nullList = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                    nullList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    nullList.add("NO DATA");
                }
                tempList.add(nullList);

                col.setGoalExcelHeader(headers);
                col.setGoalTotalFilteredRows(tempList);

            } else {
                col.setGoalExcelHeader(headers);
                col.setGoalTotalFilteredRows(totalData);
            }

        }
        if (table.equals("OVERALL_COMMENTS_ON_GOALS")) {

            col.setOverallHeader(headers);
            col.setOverallTotalFilteredRows(totalData);

        }
        if (table.equals("OVERALL_COMMENTS_ON_GOALS_ADD_REVIEWER")) {

            /*
             * it1 = headerArrayList.iterator(); it2 =
             * filteredArrayList.listIterator(); while (it2.hasNext()) {
             * List nestedList = it2.next(); it3 =
             * nestedList.listIterator(); }
             * 
             * HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             * 
             * while (it1.hasNext() && it3.hasNext()) { map.put(it1.next(),
             * it3.next().toString()); }
             * 
             * for (Map.Entry<String, String> ee : map.entrySet()) {
             * 
             * if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Section Comment")) {
             * coll.setHussain_Comments(ee.getValue().trim()); } if
             * (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Section Comment Owner User ID"
             * )) { coll.setOverallCommentUserID(ee.getValue().trim()); } }
             */
            col.setHussain_Comments("");
            col.setOverallCommentUserID("");

        }
        if (table.equals("GENPACT_VALUES")) {

            headerIterator = headers.iterator();
            dataIterator = totalData.iterator();

            while (dataIterator.hasNext()) {
                List nestedList = dataIterator.next();
                nestedIterator = nestedList.listIterator();
            }

            HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while (headerIterator.hasNext() && nestedIterator.hasNext()) {
                map1.put(headerIterator.next(), nestedIterator.next().toString());
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> ee : map1.entrySet()) {
                if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("SECTION_COMMENT")) {
                    col.setGenpactValue(ee.getValue().trim());
                }
            }

        }
        if (table.equals("OVERALL_COMMENTS_ON_POTENTIAL")) {
            col.setOverallPotHeader(headers);
            col.setOverallPotTotalFilteredRows(totalData);

        }
        if (table.equals("OVERALL_COMMENTS_POTENTIAL_REV")) {
            System.out.println("OVERALL_COMMENTS_ON_POTENTIAL_REVIEWER");
            col.setOverallPotReviewHeader(headers);
            col.setOverallPotReviewTotalFilteredRows(totalData);

        }
        if (table.equals("PERONAL_DEVELOPMENT_PLAN")) {

            System.out.println("inside pdp");

            if (totalData.size() > 1) {
                List<List<String>> sortedList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                Map trainingMap = new HashMap();
                Map competencyMap = new HashMap();
                int index = headers.indexOf("SECTION_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME");

                for (List list1 : totalData) {
                    String value = (String) list1.get(index);
                    value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
                    String num[] = value.split("\\s+");
                    if (num[0].trim().contains("Training")) {
                        trainingMap.put(Integer.parseInt(num[1].trim()), list1);
                    } else if (num[0].trim().contains("Competency")) {
                        competencyMap.put(Integer.parseInt(num[1].trim()), list1);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 1; i <= competencyMap.size(); i++) {
                    List finalList = (List) competencyMap.get(i);
                    sortedList.add(finalList);
                }
                for (int i = 1; i <= trainingMap.size(); i++) {
                    List finalList = (List) trainingMap.get(i);
                    sortedList.add(finalList);
                }
                col.setPDPHeader(headers);
                col.setPDPTotalFilteredRows(sortedList);
            } else {
                col.setPDPHeader(headers);
                col.setPDPTotalFilteredRows(totalData);
            }

        }
        if (table.equals("PERSONAL_DEV_PLAN_RATING_TRAIN")) {
            System.out.println("PERSONAL_DEVELOPEMENT_PLAN_REVIEW");

            col.setPDPReviewHeader(headers);
            col.setPDPReviewTotalFilteredRows(totalData);

        }
        if (table.equals("SUCCESSION_PLAN")) {
            col.setSuccessHeader(headers);
            col.setSuccessTotalFilteredRows(totalData);

        }
        if (table.equals("RELEASIBILITY_TIMELINE")) {

            /*
             * it1 = headerArrayList.iterator(); it2 =
             * filteredArrayList.listIterator(); while (it2.hasNext()) {
             * List nestedList = it2.next(); it3 =
             * nestedList.listIterator(); }
             * 
             * HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             * 
             * while (it1.hasNext() && it3.hasNext()) { map.put(it1.next(),
             * it3.next().toString()); }
             * 
             * for (Map.Entry<String, String> ee : map.entrySet()) {
             * 
             * if (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Section Custom Field Name"
             * )) { coll.setReleasability_CFN(ee.getValue().trim()); } if
             * (ee.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Section Custom Field Value"))
             * { if (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("n1224m")) {
             * coll.setReleasability_CFV("Next 12 to 24  Month"); } else if
             * (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("n612m")) {
             * coll.setReleasability_CFV("Next 6 to 12  Month"); } else if
             * (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("n6m")) {
             * coll.setReleasability_CFV("Next 6 Month"); } else if
             * (ee.getValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("np")) {
             * coll.setReleasability_CFV("Not Planned"); } else {
             * coll.setReleasability_CFV(" "); } } }
             */
            col.setReleasability_CFN("");
            col.setReleasability_CFV("");

        }

        if (table.equals("SIGNATURE")) {

        }

    }
    /*try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}

public List<String> getOHRListFromMore4K() {
    String columnWanted = "Employee OHR ID";
    Integer columnNo = null;
    // output all not null values to the list
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        // fileInputStream = new
        // FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("OHR_COUNT_FILE"));

        // For Rating
        System.err.println(properties.getProperty("OHR_4K"));
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("OHR_4K"));

        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        // Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);

        /*
         * for (Cell cell : firstRow) { if
         * (cell.getStringCellValue().equals(columnWanted)) { columnNo =
         * cell.getColumnIndex(); System.err.println(columnNo); } }
         */

        for (Row row : sheet) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
            if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                // Nothing in the cell in this row, skip it

            } else {
                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
                    String cellActualValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    list.add(cellActualValue.trim());
                }
                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
                    String cellActualValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    list.add(cellActualValue.trim());
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean flag = false;
    for (String str : list) {
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee OHR ID")) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    if (flag) {
        list.remove("Employee OHR ID");
    }
    return list;
}

}
```

Stack Trace--

```
competencies [[2015 Appraisal, 760004687, Genpact Values, Ana is committed to Genpact values, although she is new in the company she has been adapting very quickly, Completed]]
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
at com.genpact.dao.DataReader.getData(DataReader.java:212)
at com.genpact.templateGen.EmpTemplateGen.getTemplate(EmpTemplateGen.java:160)
at com.genpact.templateGen.EmpTemplateGen.main(EmpTemplateGen.java:113)
```

Comment: can you please put the whole stack trace of exception. That will help to find out the problem.

Comment: Also can you look into bulk collect and restrict the data that is getting passed in the ResultSet. Modify your query to just get one record first. List<String> header = new ArrayList<String>();
    String sql = "SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '" + name + "'ORDER BY COLUMN_ID ";
    System.out.println("Header sql :" + sql);.. you have not specified the query too. check if it can be tuned.

Comment: @Yeppe I cannot restrict the data and this query is only getting table names

Comment: @zombie I have attached stack trace of excetpion

Answer (score 0):

You should close your connection after (finally) you use it see [close connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java) procedure.

Comment: I have already closed the connection before creating any connection.

Comment: close every time after you use it

Comment: I have closed the connection in init block and create a connection in the constructor. So it is getting closed every time and I have checked that every time a new connection is created.