# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server] Before start of result set

Tags: java, php, soap, resultset, soap-client

I am developing a web service for e-commerce website, and i am returning all products based on some supplier_id from java into php client but it is giving me this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server] Before start of result set in C:\wamp\www\eshop\viewProductsSupplier.php:194 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\eshop\viewProductsSupplier.php(194): SoapClient->__soapCall('viewProducts', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\eshop\viewProductsSupplier.php on line 194
```

I have tried to check whether the query executes or not but it is all fine

//php code

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8090/Eshop_ecommerce/services/Eshop_ecommerce?wsdl', ['trace' => 1]);
            session_start();
            $id=array('id'=>@$_SESSION['supplierId']);
            $response=$soapclient->__soapCall("viewProducts",$id);
            if (isset($response->Name))
            {
                print $response;
            }
            else
            {
                print "Data is null";
            }
```

//Java code

```
ViewProductsResponse res = new ViewProductsResponse();
                Class.forName(driver);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String Query=null;
                String in=viewProducts.getViewProductsRequest();
                if(!in.isEmpty())
                {
                    Query="SELECT * FROM product";
                }
                else
                {
                    Query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_supplier_id='"+viewProducts.getViewProductsRequest()+"'";
                }
                ProductArray pa=new ProductArray();
                ResultSet result= stmt.executeQuery(Query);
                //System.out.println(result);
                while(result.next())
                {
                    Product p= new Product();
                    //System.out.println(result.getString("product_id"));
                    p.setId(result.getString("product_id"));
                    p.setName(result.getString("product_name"));
                    p.setPrice(result.getString("product_price"));
                    p.setStock(result.getString("product_stock"));
                    String supplierNameQuery="SELECT supplier_id,supplier_name FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id='"+result.getString("product_supplier_id")+"'";
                    ResultSet resultSupplierName = stmt.executeQuery(supplierNameQuery);
                    p.setSupplierName(resultSupplierName.getString("supplier_name"));
                    String catQuery="SELECT * FROM product_category WHERE category_id='"+result.getString("product_category_id")+"'";
                    ResultSet resCat= stmt.executeQuery(catQuery);
                    p.setCategoryName(resCat.getString("category_name"));
                    pa.setProduct(p);
                    res.setProducts(pa);
                }
                //res.setViewProductsResponse("Data Entered");
                return res;
```

where as i expect it to print all the resulting products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) returned from [Statement#executeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) is positioned before the first row (see linked-in JavaDoc). In order for such `ResultSet` to point to the first row it needs re-positioned to it, for example using the [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) method. This is done for the outer `SELECT` but not for the two inner ones. Further the return value from `next()` call needs to be checked in order to see if there is any row at all in that `ResultSet`.

This can be achieved for example like this:

```
 if(resultSupplierName.next()) {
     p.setSupplierName(resultSupplierName.getString("supplier_name"));
 }
 if(resCat.next()) {
     p.setCategoryName(resCat.getString("category_name"));
 }
```

Please note that the posted code has other open issues, for example the JDBC resources are not closed. I would strongly suggest to look either into JEE or Spring (giving that the code apparently runs in aplication server) or at least at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225221/closing-database-connections-in-java). Further is the code prone to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: thanks for your help ... it works ... and also i will follow advice about JDBC thanks again !!!